# Has anyone used AWS system manager parameter in data pipeline, to allocate value to a parameter in pipeline?

Tags: aws-data-pipeline

```
"id": "myS3Bucket",
"type": "String",
"default": "\"aws ssm get-parameters --names variable --query \"Parameters[*].{myS3Bucket:Value}\"\""
```

I tried this ,
Where I created a variable in AWS parameter and was able to retrieve the value using this command in AWS CLI, but not able to retrieve the value and send it in my pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Its not feasible the way, you are trying to achieve it. DP looks at it as a String and not AWS CLI command to execute to fulfill the value . 
When declaring String parameter, either you can define static value like `s3://tst-data-bucket` or dynamic derived value from another parameter(runtime or compile time or both) `s3://#{anotherparameter}/@actualStartTime`.
*To achieve your desired result*, you can fetch the AWS SM parameter & pass the value in DP activation command, howsoever you are activating your DP either through lambda or cli bash script.